# Generating sql statements in c# - insert tabe value into new table

Tags: c#, sql

I'm writing a small program that converts csv files into a seried of insert statements into the database. The program has no knowledge of the database, so the statements written are a once-off thing, they can't be dynamic.

Now, each dataset has it's own guid, and I want to have the statements query the database to determine if the dataset exists, based on it's name. So I have:

```
sw.WriteLine("-- Determine if dataset exists from school name");
sw.WriteLine(string.Format(
"INSERT INTO DataSets (Guid, DataSets ) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DataSets WHERE DataSetName = '{1}')",
Guid,
DataSetName 
));
```

(Please correct me if I'm wrong, sql really isn't my forte)
Now, the next issue is that the Guid for the dataset is used in some of the other tables, such as:

```
string sql = string.Format(
                    "INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', {3}, '{4}');",
                    object.value1
                    object.value1
                    object.value1
                    object.value1
                    Guid
```

'Guid' cannot be used as a variable in c# though, it could be either a new Guid (if 'datasets' doesn't exist in the database) or an existing guid (if 'datasets' exists, get the existing guid)

So I will need something like:

```
string sql = string.Format(
                    "INSERT INTO Table1 (Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', {3});",
                    object.value1
                    object.value1
                    object.value1
                    object.value1
string sql2 = string.Format("INSERT INTO Table1 (Data5) VALUES (SELECT Guid FROM Datasets WHERE DataSetName = '{0}');
                    Guid
                    );
```

Is this a good (even valid?) way of going about this?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I have a function that replaces any commas with '' before the data is inserted. I'm still working on more measures, but the data should be sanitized before this code is run.

Comment: commas aren't your only problem. Use parameters

Comment: Can I actually use parameters? This is a program that generates a sql query that is saved and used at a later date (not my idea, I assure you). As I understand from a bit of reading, parameters keep the query data away from the query code, so there  will be no query string as such, unless I can separate the parameters as local variables in the sql query. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

first of all, like others pointed out, you are open to SQL injection, so, use parameter for SqlCommand is a better choice. you can find lots of examples.

however, if the code is just for converting csv to insert, and it is really unlikely someone will try to hack the program, I would say it is ok.

bascially, what you described is ok. But

```
   string sql2 = string.Format("INSERT INTO Table1 (Data5) VALUES (SELECT Guid FROM Datasets WHERE DataSetName = '{0}');
                Guid
                );
```

you should first check whether it returns guid or null

```
   SELECT Guid FROM Datasets WHERE DataSetName = '{0}'
```

then decide whether create a new guid and insert.

If you are doing import just for once, you do not even need check whether the guid exists. you create a guid from code, insert it into sql. it is because it is guid, the probability of creating same guid in one batch is really really small although it is not zero, theoretically.

- you do NOT have to connect to database if you do NOT need to know what guid are already in the database (i.e. you only need to import once). you can use a list of track all guid you used.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm already ensuring the Guid is not null, as the first block of code I had will run first, which will creat a new guid if it is null.

I'm checking if the guid exists to match the new data with any existing data, since I want them to be referenced by the same guid if they have the same name.

Comment: Not using parameters because "it is really unlikely someone will try to hack the program" is very dangerous advice. Get in the habit of always using them, even if you're "sure" they are not necessary.

Comment: Alright, I'm looking into using parameters. A few questions: 1. Can I do without the SqlConnection, as this program has no access to the server. 2. How do I get the command object to write the command (not send it to a server)?

Comment: Sometimes, when we import data, we only need to use the import once, the key thing is to import data correctly and faster. that's why sometimes, we can use non parameter sqlcommand. of course, it does not mean it is the best choice, but it gets job done.

Comment: @Irish, I did not know you were generating SQL strings and not command objects. You are correct, Prepare statements need a database connection so they know the column types, sizes, et al.